# Is a half-staffed foresters lodge just as efficient per worker as a fully staffed one?

Tags: banished

If I have a forester's lodge with half his circle of influence covered by my city (or by mountains, water, etc) can I just staff it with 2/4 people and be confident that I'm getting the same output per worker as a fully staffed forester's lodge with no obstructions in it's circle of influence?

If the answer generalizes to gatherers/herbalist/hunters please note that as well.

Comment: Interesting, but I think you're actually asking 2 parts of one question: Half labor (2/4 workers) and half available land (covered by your city/mountain). Mixing the two while trying to test effectiveness could confuse the results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated:**

The first experiment was flawed (though the numbers were correct) foresters were not working in full grown forest. This next experiment is done few years later in a fully developed forest. Again - each experiment starts from the same savegame. Each number is averaged of 4 runs.

```
Full circle
 4 workers: 261 logs/year | 65 logs/person/year
 2 workers: 135 logs/year | 67 logs/person/year
 1 worker:  75 logs/year  | 75 logs/person/year

Half circle*
 4 workers: 157 logs/year | 39 logs/person/year
 2 workers: 121 logs/yea  | 60 logs/person/year
 1 worker:  58 logs/year  | 58 logs/person/year
```

* - only half of the circle was available for forestry other half was filled with pastures and fields:

[image: Picture of Experiment]

Comment: Nice! But are you sure your numbers aren't backwards? How is it possible a half circle would produce more wood than a full circle?

Comment: How would education affect the results? would there be an improvement as well?

Comment: Every worker was educated and using iron tools. They were living and delivering logs just outside the circle. Only improvement i can think of is having market nearby: then walks for tools, firewood and jackets would be much shorter, but workers rarely go shopping. The best way of improving foresters lodge is to have housing and drop off point nearby.

Comment: What about foresters that are only planting trees? Normally I just have forester lodges on plant only and use laborers to harvest the trees, as this seems to be more efficient.